# ExtJs Column values keeps shifting or gets out of alignment when i change screen resolution

Tags: javascript, extjs

> Using  a combobox 'abc' so when changing screen zoom percentage it's values
> gets out of alignment and enters other columns.Position is given as
> 'relative' for the values.How can this be solved?

Comment: Hi Aakash. Thanks for your post. Please add a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home), which helps others to help you faster. Simply setup a combobox and the steps to reproduce the behaviour. Thanks

Comment: Is it the picker content or the input field content?